# What are the benefits or shortcomings of a moss wall?

Tags: environmental-impact, plants, city-living, air-pollution

I'm considering to put up a small moss wall in my workplace. What benefits or shortcomings should be considered regarding inhabitants' health and environment impact of a moss wall?

**Update:** It's an office place with mild lighting and I'm planning to spray the wall with water to keep alive. Dormant moss seems ineffective to me - but that's the question I'm tying to get some answers to.

Comment: Somehow you must have gotten the idea of putting it up, so why don't you start with what you think the benefits are?

Comment: There is unlikely to be enough light of the right colors to grow inside , with no natural light. A dedicated , close LED light may be successful  . I am getting good aquarium plant growth with LED lights . And fluorescents like Gro-Lux..